# Spring RMI. Do not log specific exceptions

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, rmi, error-logging

I have an application separated in two modules: FrontEnd and BackEnd. Both connected using RMI.

My problem is that some exceptions are thrown from the BackEnd and should not be logged.

I get this entry in my log

```
16:46:01,208 WARN  [RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor] Processing of RmiServiceExporter remote call resulted in fatal exception: com.garson.lightball.wizard.IWizardService.process
com.garson.lightball.wizard.WizardRedirectionException
    at com.garson.lightball.views.menu.menus.scope.MenusScopeWizardService._process(MenusScopeWizardService.java:59)
    at com.garson.lightball.wizard.WizardService.process(WizardService.java:75)
    at com.garson.lightball.wizard.commons.AbstractBusinessWizardService.step_business(AbstractBusinessWizardService.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I would like to avoid any logging regarding **com.garson.lightball.wizard.WizardRedirectionException**

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Adrian

Comment: Configure your logging Framework to ignore this package / class

Comment: What if theres a lot more of other exceptions I would like to not see in my log? Should add them one by one?